# Google App Engine Cron

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, rss

I have an application deployed on Google App Engine that relies heavily on cron to work properly. I have a few admin servlets available for me to tweak a few things, but other than that, the bulk of the application is cron work.

I have a Servlet defined that responds to cron requests that fire every hour. The cron job looks at an RSS feed and identifies items published within the last hour. When it finds one, it pushes a notification to users of an Android app (that is the end goal).

If my understanding of App Engine is correct, Google can essentially stop instances of my application if there isn't enough traffic to warrant the application being up, and when a request comes in, if the application isn't running, a new one will be spun up.

For my application, this can be problematic because when the cron job is triggered, it only looks for RSS items that were published one hour ago or sooner, and if the application is taken down, obviously the cron jobs won't be run.

Essentially, I need the cron job to run every hour, but because there really isn't any other 'traffic' coming to the application to speak of, I believe my application is being undeployed. Is there anything I can do to fix that?

I was thinking about scheduling a cron job to run every minute, that would basically serve as a keep alive for the application, but that seems wasteful.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have cron jobs, they will be run even if your application is not deployed (the cron request will spawn one instance). At least that's how it was a while back. Do you have a source (or indication) that says otherwise?

Comment: No, but I guess I assumed that the application had to be running in order for the cron jobs to be fired. Since the cron jobs are 'internal' to the application, I assumed they were treated differently than someone browsing to my application, it not being up, and a new instance being spun up.

Comment: I don't think so. Should just be "normal" HTTP request (with some special headers and more access rights), fired by some server at Google (not from inside your application). But let's wait for someone else to weigh in, my App Engine experience is a bit rusty.

Comment: I hear you. It's definitely an HTTP request that gets made to the application when the cron job is triggered, but I was thinking that the cron job wouldn't be fired if the application wasn't up. First, the cron job gets fired. Second, the Servlet that is designated as handling the request gets a request. I can see how the HTTP request would trigger the application to be spun up, but the initial cron firing off is what I was thinking wouldn't happen if the application was taken down due to a lack of traffic.

Comment: The cron scheduler is part of the App Engine environment and not your application per se, so a request from cron is like (but differentiable from) a request from a user. Your application is never 'undeployed', instances (for auto-scaling modules) are simply shutdown after an idle period.  When your cron runs, if no instances are running, one will be created.

Comment: Do you really need cron jobs? For example, why not use something like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) which does the polling on your behalf and just fat pings you when the feed is updated?